# How do I write a DXF code for a SIMPLE BLOCK?

Tags: vba, dxf

I'm manually writing a dxf file. My question is: How do I write a DXF code for a SIMPLE BLOCK (containing for example one line)?

I'm really lost. I tried:

```
0 
SECTION
 2 
 BLOCKS
 0
BLOCK
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbBlockBegin
  2
MySampleBlock
10
0
20
0
30
0
  3
MySampleBlock
......
0
ENDBLK
```

Comment: read reference https://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf , what concretly are you trying to achieve? btw, i have written excel vba macro to write some text at XY position in DXF file, if it will be usefull for you

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for your response.

Your mentioned reference, like all native autocad manuals, are absolutelly useless, because hasn't any examples. Very technical, very complete, bleh, bleh, bleh, but absolutelly useless for novices as me.

I only need a simple inserting block example dxf file :)

Comment: please read this http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/dxf/min3d.html , I just saved example from the end of this page to .txt file and changed extension to .dxf and it works

Answer (score 0):

Save that text as .dxf and open as picture

```
    0
    SECTION
    2
    ENTITIES
    0
    3DFACE
    8
    1
    62
    1
    10
    -0.5
    20
    -0.5
    30
    -0.5
    11
    -0.5
    21
    0.5
    31
    -0.5
    12
    0.5
    22
    0.5
    32
    -0.5
    13
    0.5
    23
    -0.5
    33
    -0.5
    0
    3DFACE
    8
    1
    62
    1
    10
    -0.5
    20
    -0.5
    30
    -0.5
    11
    0.5
    21
    -0.5
    31
    -0.5
    12
    0
    22
    -0.5
    32
    0.5
    13
    0
    23
    -0.5
    33
    0.5
    0
    LINE
    8
    1
    62
    1
    10
    0
    20
    -0.5
    30
    0.5
    11
    0
    21
    0.5
    31
    -0.5
    0
    ENDSEC
    0
    EOF
```

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for sour help and patience

Autocad response: "Invalid or incomplete DXF input -- drawing discarded."

Anyway, I know how to write a minimal dxf (lines, arcs, etc.). In need to learn how to manipulate BLOCKS.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have autocad.. I used simple IrfanView to open it